# How to use g:render in g:select for optionValue?

Tags: grails

I have a g:select statement that looks like the following:

```
<g:select id="gearbox" name="gearbox.id" from="${com.nppc.mes.energyusage.Gearbox.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="${ {"${it.gearboxType} - (${it.gearboxRatio})"} }" required="" value="${gearboxVoltageInstance?.gearbox?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

I have added an optionValue attribute: `optionValue="${ {"${it.gearboxType} - (${it.gearboxRatio})"} }"`

This works as I want.

However, I want to show my domain object, Gearboxes the same everywhere.  I have created a template, and am able to use the g:render tag on my show.gsp.

What I can't figure out is how to get something like this to work:

`optionValue="<g:render template="/shared/gearbox" model:="[gearbox:it]"/>"`

Is it possible to use templates to generate the content that goes into an optionValue?

Answer (score 0):

You could hack around it, but it feels like bad design to me.

The right way to do something like is seems to be to add a helper method to your Gearbox domain class

```
static transients = [ 'renderedValue' ]

def getRenderedValue(){
   "$gearboxType - $gearboxRatio"
}
```

Then, you can just call optionValue="${ it.renderedValue }".

Also, if you specify a toString() in your domain class, this would be used to generate the default rendered value.

Comment: Are you offering to render templates in domain method as a better design?

Answer (score 0):

Tags can be used as regular functions in Groovy code. Like:

```
optionValue="${g.render(template: '/shared/gearbox', model: [gearbox: it])}"
```

Comment: thx - that worked.  Just needed to keep the syntax "${{...}}" to get it to work though.  Not sure why the extra curlys are needed, but when I add them, it work. :-)